# Mixing Chaplin with other Backbone extensions

Tags: backbone.js, chaplinjs

I'm working on an application written with Chaplin. We want our REST to be HATEOAS, and we were thinking about using [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) for a standard link structure in our JSON. I see that [there is a Backbone extension that works with HA](https://github.com/mikekelly/backbone.hal)L, but this makes its own `Model` and `Collection` classes. Chaplin also makes its own `Model` and `Collection` classes. Is there a simple way to make a "master" `Model` and `Collection` class that combines both HAL and Chaplin's Model and `Collection` classes?

Comment: Have a look at this [ticket](https://github.com/chaplinjs/chaplin/issues/209). It's essentially the same problem and it works just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing. Someone come up with a better answer, please!

models/base/model.coffee:

```
module.exports = class Model extends Chaplin.Model
  parse: HAL.Model::parse
  url: HAL.Model::url
  isNew: HAL.Model::isNew
  constructor: (attrs, options) ->
    super @parse(_.clone attrs), options
```

models/base/collection.coffee:

```
module.exports = class Collection extends Chaplin.Collection
  # Use the project base model per default, not Chaplin.Model
  model: Model
  parse: HAL.Collection::parse
  url: HAL.Collection::url
  reset: HAL.Collection::reset
  constructor: (attrs, options) ->
    super @parse(_.clone attrs), options
```